# If T and T' are two topologies on X and T ⊂ T', what does the connectedness of X in one topology imply about connectedness in the other topology?

Tags: general-topology

**Here is what I have**: If (X,T) is disconnected, then  there exists a separation (U,V), where U and V are disjoint open non-empty subsets of (X,T) Since we are given T ⊂ T', then U and V are open non-empty subsets of (X,T'), and their union is X. Then, (U,V) is a separation of (X,T'), so (X,T') is disconnected. Conversely, if (X,T') is connected, then (X,T) is connected. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct. Another way to see it:  the identity $\textrm{id}:(X,\tau') \to (X,\tau)$ is continuous and preserves connectedness.